# start Ops Manager on a mongo repl set with keyfile authentication mechanism

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I have successfully deployed a mongo replication set sharing a keyfile between my three nodes.
It works fine, the problem is when I try to start ops manager service:

```
[root@xxx:/etc]# service mongodb-mms start
Starting pre-flight checks
Failure to connect to configured mongo instance: 
Config{loadBalance=false, encryptedCredentials=false, ssl='false', 
dbNames='[mmsdb, mmsdbprovisionlog, mmsdbautomation, mmsdbserverlog, 
mmsdbpings, mmsdbprofile, mmsdbrrd, mmsdbconfig, mmsdblogcollection, 
mmsdbjobs, mmsdbagentlog, mmsdbbilling, backuplogs, automationcore, 
monitoringstatus, mmsdbautomationlog, automationstatus, cloudconf, backupdb, 
mmsdbprovisioning, mmsdbqueues]', uri=mongodb://xxx1:27017,xxx2:27017,xxx3:27017} Error: Command failed with 
error 13: 'not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1, 
$db: "admin" }' on server xxx1:27017. The full response is { "operationTime" 
: { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1517416044, "i" : 1 } }, "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : 
"not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1, $db: 
\"admin\" }", "code" : 13, "codeName" : "Unauthorized", "$clusterTime" : { 
"clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1517416044, "i" : 1 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "fh+qyjJ0L8c8zCx0U672aJdZdUw=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "6516848947321896961" } } } }
Pre-flight checks failed. Service can not start.
```

I'm not authorized on database admin..

I have tried to configure another repl set in which I have commented this part of the mongod.conf file

```
security:
  keyFile: /opt/mongo/mongo-keyfile
```

i can start the service correctly. what is wrong?

Comment: I think you only need to run mongod service on your server with "service mongod start ", for details you can see on this website, I think the error is same.[How to Fix Mongodb OPS Manager Failure to connect to configured mongo instance](https://www.siskom.xyz/2018/05/how-to-fix-mongodb-ops-manager-failur-to-connect.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your MongoDB server is starting *with authentication enabled*, but the ops manager service is trying to connect and manage the server (starting with the listDatabases command) without being authenticated.

The MongoDB docs include a useful tutorial on [Enforce Keyfile Access Control in a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/), which includes this pertinent comment:

> Running [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) with the --keyFile command-line option or the [security.keyFile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.keyFile) configuration file setting enforces both [Internal Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/) and [Role-Based Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/).